# PHP version causes different behavior of skipping lines for the same code

Tags: php

```
while($c=fgets(STDIN)){
    if($c===PHP_EOL){
        continue;
    }
    else {
        echo $c;
    }
}
```

When the above code is called from the command line in php 5.3.8, it prints the rows in the input file, and skips any empty lines. However, in php 5.2.6, it does not skip over the empty lines.

Is there any way of changing the code to make it skip over empty lines in the lder versions as well?

Comment: Are you sure that `PHP_EOL` is the same in both environments and that it matches the `EOL` char for the file in question?

Comment: I thought PHP_EOL is a predefined constant, and therefore should work on any system, see here: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Comment: It is predefiend but its mapped to platforms EOL. So if youre switching between platforms and the file youre reading was created on a different platform then the `EOL` may not match.

Comment: Oh I see, that isn't very helpful of it.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the condition to

```
if(ord($c[0])==0x0a || ord($c[0])==0x0d)
```

This should work on any platform.

See [ord](http://php.net/ord)

Comment: thankyou! this works. can you send me a link to documentation though? I want to understand it better

Comment: oh I see now, it's ascii, awesome, tnx

Comment: This string gives different outputs on different servers...help!

`$lat = ((ord($str[7]) << 24) | (ord($str[8]) << 16) | (ord($str[9]) << 8) | (ord($str[10]))) / 1000000;`

If its a negative number, I get something like 4042 instead of -0.05.

Comment: @Reddox could you ask a separate question  for this issue? The problem of OP and your problem are not same

Answer (score 2):

The difference probably caused by php.ini change, not the version. Check `auto_detect_line_endings` key in your php config file or if you have the access try;

```
<?php
    ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
?>
```

`auto_detect_line_endings` is used by `fgets`. `PHP_EOL` always gets the correct end of line character depending on the OS but `fgets` may fail if you don't set `auto_detect_line_endings` to true.

Comment: Ok I just tried this. In php.ini it was set to "Off". I changed to "On", and it is still not working..

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = str_replace("\r\n", "", $c);
```

P.S. I don't think that php version is significant. It seems like something wrong with configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I think there might be a problem with configuration as well, there is also a php warning, I will ask my host provider about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need trailing spaces, you can use:

```
$c = rtrim( $c, "\n\r");
if( $c == ''){
  continue;
}
```

if you do, you should probably check string length or use this:

```
if( ($c{0} == "\n") || ($c{0} == "\r")){
  continue;
}
```

Comment: Recommend using `if( $c == '' )` instead of `if( empty($c) )` in the first example; "0" might be a valid input.

Comment: @Phoenix With `fgets` string contains `\n` resp. `\r\n`, therefor when your string begins with `\n` or `\r`, it contains just line break.

Comment: That is true, but suppose the user enters the sequence `0\n`.  After running it through `rtrim()`, `$c` now contains the string "0", which would cause `empty($c)` to return `true`, which might not result in the correct behavior for this application.